# Show $O(1) a.s.+o(1)a.s.=O(1)a.s.$ (not easy)

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, asymptotics

Let $Y_n$ and $X_n$ be two sequences of random variables.

Say that $Y_n=O(1)$ almost surely if $\exists M>0$ such that $ P(\limsup_n\{\lvert Y_n\rvert \leq M\} )=1$, and

say that $Y_n=o(1)$ a.s. if $\forall \delta>0$ we have $ P(\limsup_n\{\lvert Y_n\rvert > \delta\} )=0$.

**Question**
If $Y_n=O(1)$a.s. and $X_n=o(1)$a.s., how would you show that $Y_n+X_n=O(1)$a.s.?

Comment: These definitions don't look right. According to them $Y_n = o(1) \text{ a.s.}$ if e.g. $Y_{2n} = 0 \text{ a.s.}$ and $Y_{2n+1} = 2n+1 \text{ a.s.}$. But a subsequence of an almost surely $O(1)$ or $o(1)$ sequence should also be such. I would expect the definitions to say $$P(\liminf_n \{ \lvert Y_n\rvert \leqslant C\}) = 1\,.$$

Comment: In page 8 of http://www2.math.uu.se/~svante/papers/sjN6.pdf

Comment: He wrote $X_n=O(a_n)a.s. \iff \limsup_n \lvert X_n\rvert/ a_n <\infty$a.s. It is equivalent to $P(\limsup_n \{\lvert X_n\rvert/ a_n <\infty\})=1$ right?

Comment: Also $X_n=o(a_n)$a.s. if $X_n/a_n\to 0$ a.s. It is equivalent to say $P(\limsup_n \{ \lvert X_n\rvert>\epsilon\})=0$. That is $P(\liminf_n\{ \lvert X_n\rvert \leq \epsilon\})=1$

Comment: @DanielFischer From these observations, I conclude that you are right! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note $\omega \in \limsup_{n\to\infty} \{|Y_n| \le M\}$ if and only if $|Y_n(\omega)| \le M$ for infinitely many $n$.  Which actually implies $\liminf_{n\to\infty} |Y_n(\omega)| \le M$.  (Although the converse doesn't quite hold, but $\liminf_{n\to\infty} |Y_n(\omega)| < M$ does imply $\omega \in \limsup_{n\to\infty} \{|Y_n| \le M\}$.)  In other words, the notation is very confusing.

Next, $\omega \in \limsup_{n\to\infty} \{|X_n| > \delta\}$ if an only if $|X_n(\omega)| > \delta$ for infinitely many $n$.  So $\omega \notin \limsup_{n\to\infty} \{|X_n| > \delta\}$ if and only if $|X_n(\omega)| \le \delta$ for all but finitely many $n$.

Now suppose $Y_n$ is $O(1)$ a.s. and $X_n$ is $o(1)$ a.s.  Then there exists $M>0$, and for all $\delta>0$, we have that with probability 1 we have
$$ |Y_n(\omega)| \le M \text{ for infinitely many $n$, and } |X_n(\omega)| \le \delta \text{ for all but finitely many $n$} .$$
But this means that with probability 1
$$ |X_n(\omega) + Y_n(\omega)| \le M + \delta  \text{ for infinitely many $n$} $$
because if you remove at most a finite number of elements from an infinite set, it is still infinite.

Comment: It looks nice! When dealing with limit superior of random variables I'm used to work with sets rather than numbers. I will read your answer again.

Comment: Yes.  My first paragraph is simply saying the notation is potentially confusing.  One has to realize that the $\{$ and $\}$ are set delimiters rather than parentheses by a different symbol.

Comment: I didn't find anything illogical in your answer. Excellent! I perfectly understood your braces symbols. It is the inverse image of $\lvert Y_n\rvert\leq M$. Thank you ;)

Answer (score 0):

The result holds even if $X_n=O_{a.s.}(1)$ because
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty}|X_n+Y_n|\le \limsup_{n\to\infty}|X_n|+\limsup_{n\to\infty}|Y_n|<\infty \quad\text{a.s.}
$$

Comment: In the first inequality you treated $X_n$ and $Y_n$ as numbers?

Comment: What $\limsup_n \lvert X_n\rvert+\limsup_n \lvert Y_n\rvert$ means? The limit superior of a sequence of sets is a set. Likewise, the limit superior of the inverse images of sequences of random variables is a set. Are you summing sets?

Comment: @CelineHarumi Check p.8 in Janson's paper. For each $\omega$, $\{X_n(\omega)\}$ and $\{Y_n(\omega)\}$ are just sequences of numbers.

Comment: $\limsup_{n\to\infty} |Z_n| < \infty$ a.s. is not the same as $Z_n$ being $O(1)$.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith It's the same as $O_{a.s.}(1)$.

Comment: Not according to the definition given by the OP.  That says there exists $M>0$ such that $\limsup_{n\to\infty} |Z_n|  \le M$ a.s.

Comment: Oh, I see.  We are doing lim sup of numbers versus lim sup of sets.  How confusing.